# Can't apply for on click function on each of the checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply for onclick function on each of the checkbox that is being added in a datatable row.

Here's the image:

[image]

Now the issue is that I am writing a code like this

```
    var tablei = $('#domains_list').DataTable();
    $('#domains_list').find("input[name='chk[]']:checked").each(function()
                    {
                         $(this).on('click',function () 
                           {
                               // make a class change to the parent tr having the checkbox;
                           } );
                    }
               });
```

But the problem is, I can't write the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need each to bind event. Also you should check `checked` in the click handler

Use

```
$('#domains_list').find("input[name='chk[]']").on('click', function() {
    //Perform your operation
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('smclass');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('smclass');
    }
});
```

OR

```
$('#domains_list').find("input[name='chk[]']").on('click', function() {
    //Perform your operation
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('smclass', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to iterate over elements individually to bind the event:

```
  $('#domains_list').find("input[name='chk[]']:checked").click(function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass('smclass');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use on()...

```
var tablei = $('#domains_list').DataTable();
$('#domains_list').on('click', "input[name='chk[]']", function ()  {
    // Verify here if the checkbox is checked or not, but you could prefer the change event
    // make a class change to the parent tr having the checkbox;
});
```

But the better way is to attach then event when you add the row (if you are able to do that).

The manual: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Because all of your checkboxes have the same function attach to it, so you dont need to loop all the element using each. An easier way to do that

```
$('document').on('click', "input[name='chk[]']:checked", function(){

   //make sure you reset all tr before applying new class
   $(this).closest('tr').addClass('custom-class');
});
```

Comment: Using delegates is a good idea, but you have a syntax error. And `:checked` is most likely wrong.

Comment: i forgot the selector uses the single quotes, thanks